# Problemas com LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Estou quebrando a cabeça há alguns dias com SQL em algo que deve ser bem simples, mas não consigo resolver.

Estou querendo obter todos os dados da tabela [NumOrdem] inclusive os que não constam na tabela [ItemNotas] com o código SQL abaixo:

```
SELECT OrdensProducao.NumOrdem AS 'OP'
   ,OrdensProducao.NomeCliente AS 'Cliente'
   ,OrdensProducao.Descricao AS 'Descrição' 
   ,OrdensProducao.TipoProduto AS 'Produto'
   ,NomeAgencia AS 'Agência'
   ,OrdensProducao.DtEmissao
   ,SPreco AS 'Valor Fechado'
   ,SCustosComissoes AS 'Comissão'
   ,(SPreco - SCustosComissoes - SCustosMat - SCustosTerc - SCustosImpostos - SCustosFin - SCustosVenOutros) AS 'Contr Marginal'
   ,(SPreco - SCustosComissoes - SCustosMat - SCustosTerc - SCustosImpostos - SCustosFin - SCustosVenOutros - SCustosMO) AS 'Lucro'
   ,SUM(ItemNota.ValorTotal) AS 'Faturado'
FROM
    ((OrdensProducao INNER JOIN OrcHdr ON OrdensProducao.NumOrdem = OrcHdr.NumOrcamento)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ItemNota ON OrcHdr.NumOrcamento = ItemNota.NumOrdem)
     INNER JOIN NotasFiscais ON ItemNota.ObjID_Nota=NotasFiscais.ObjID

WHERE
    (NotasFiscais.NaturezaOperacao IS NULL OR (NOT NotasFiscais.NaturezaOperacao LIKE 'doa*' OR NotasFiscais.NaturezaOperacao LIKE 'reme*')) AND
    (ItemNota.Devolucao IS NULL OR ItemNota.Devolucao<> 'D') AND
    (NotasFiscais.Situacao IS NULL OR NotasFiscais.Situacao = 'N') AND
    (ItemNota.Fatura IS NULL OR ItemNota.Fatura = 'F')

GROUP BY
    OrdensProducao.NumOrdem
   ,OrdensProducao.NomeCliente
   ,OrdensProducao.Descricao 
   ,OrdensProducao.TipoProduto
   ,NomeAgencia
   ,OrdensProducao.DtEmissao
   ,SPreco
   ,SCustosComissoes
   ,(SPreco - SCustosComissoes - SCustosMat - SCustosTerc - SCustosImpostos - SCustosFin - SCustosVenOutros)
   ,(SPreco - SCustosComissoes - SCustosMat - SCustosTerc - SCustosImpostos - SCustosFin - SCustosVenOutros - SCustosMO)
ORDER BY
    OrdensProducao.NumOrdem
```

Mas obtenho apenas os dados equivalentes das duas tabelas! Se retiro a tabela [NotasFicais], funciona perfeitamente, mas preciso do 'WHERE' dependente dela. Tenho quase certeza que é algo com os relacionamentos, mas não consigo resolver.

Comment: Não seria o caso de usar LEFT também com NotasFiscais, em vez de INNER?

Comment: Já tentei também. Mas não é necessário pois todos os registros em NotasFiscais existem em ItensNota

Comment: Sim, mas sua consulta só trará os ItensNota cujas NF atenderem às condições do WHERE.

Comment: Troca a ordem: primeiros os INNER JOINS, depois os OUTERS. Nunca um OUTER e depois um INNER. Você quebra a lógica do seu OUTER.

Comment: @rodrigogq, poderia me ajudar a montar essa linha na ordem correta, por favor? Estou iniciando com SQL ainda..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tabela `ItemNota` possui dois `IDs` (Não me pergunte porque, não fui eu quem criou o BD) e o ID que liga com a tabela de `Notas` é a `ObjID_Notas`.

Sobre as relações, fiz o seguinte:

```
FROM
    OrdensProducao 
    INNER JOIN OrcHdr ON OrdensProducao.NumOrdem = OrcHdr.NumOrcamento 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (ItemNota INNER JOIN NotasFiscais ON ItemNota.ObjID_Nota = NotasFiscais.ObjID) ON OrdensProducao.NumOrcamento = ItemNota.NumOrdem
```

Não sei se é a maneira mais correta, mas consegui fazer assim.

Comment: Está correto sim! E você conseguiu fazer aquilo que te fosse, primeiro os INNER JOIN, pois os que estão entre parênteses vão primeiro, e depois os OUTER!

Comment: Cassio, se existe alguma outra resposta que respondeu à sua pergunta, marque-a como certo. Caso contrário, marque sua própria resposta como certa. Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer o seguinte (a parte comentada é onde eu mudei somente):

```
SELECT OrdensProducao.NumOrdem AS 'OP'
   ,OrdensProducao.NomeCliente AS 'Cliente'
   ,OrdensProducao.Descricao AS 'Descrição' 
   ,OrdensProducao.TipoProduto AS 'Produto'
   ,NomeAgencia AS 'Agência'
   ,OrdensProducao.DtEmissao
   ,SPreco AS 'Valor Fechado'
   ,SCustosComissoes AS 'Comissão'
   ,(SPreco - SCustosComissoes - SCustosMat - SCustosTerc - SCustosImpostos - SCustosFin - SCustosVenOutros) AS 'Contr Marginal'
   ,(SPreco - SCustosComissoes - SCustosMat - SCustosTerc - SCustosImpostos - SCustosFin - SCustosVenOutros - SCustosMO) AS 'Lucro'
   ,SUM(ItemNota.ValorTotal) AS 'Faturado'

-- esta é o original.. vou mudar um pouco a forma para entender melhor...
-- FROM
--    ((OrdensProducao INNER JOIN OrcHdr ON OrdensProducao.NumOrdem = OrcHdr.NumOrcamento)
--     LEFT OUTER JOIN ItemNota ON OrcHdr.NumOrcamento = ItemNota.NumOrdem)
--     INNER JOIN NotasFiscais ON ItemNota.ObjID_Nota=NotasFiscais.ObjID

FROM
    -- todas as ordens...
    OrdensProducao
INNER JOIN OrcHdr ON
    -- E que estejam associadas com 'OrcHdr'
    OrdensProducao.NumOrdem = OrcHdr.NumOrcamento
LEFT OUTER JOIN NotasFiscais ON
    -- que TALVEZ possuam notas fiscais
    ItemNota.ObjID_Nota=NotasFiscais.ObjID
--
--  Acho que este ponto esta errado né? Não seria algo como ItemNota.NotaID = NotasFiscais.NotaId ?????????
-- LEFT OUTER JOIN ItemNota ON
--    OrcHdr.NumOrcamento = ItemNota.NumOrdem
--

WHERE
    (NotasFiscais.NaturezaOperacao IS NULL OR (NOT NotasFiscais.NaturezaOperacao LIKE 'doa*' OR NotasFiscais.NaturezaOperacao LIKE 'reme*')) AND
    (ItemNota.Devolucao IS NULL OR ItemNota.Devolucao<> 'D') AND
    (NotasFiscais.Situacao IS NULL OR NotasFiscais.Situacao = 'N') AND
    (ItemNota.Fatura IS NULL OR ItemNota.Fatura = 'F')

GROUP BY
    OrdensProducao.NumOrdem
   ,OrdensProducao.NomeCliente
   ,OrdensProducao.Descricao 
   ,OrdensProducao.TipoProduto
   ,NomeAgencia
   ,OrdensProducao.DtEmissao
   ,SPreco
   ,SCustosComissoes
   ,(SPreco - SCustosComissoes - SCustosMat - SCustosTerc - SCustosImpostos - SCustosFin - SCustosVenOutros)
   ,(SPreco - SCustosComissoes - SCustosMat - SCustosTerc - SCustosImpostos - SCustosFin - SCustosVenOutros - SCustosMO)
ORDER BY
    OrdensProducao.NumOrdem
```

Acho que o erro estava no INNER para o LEFT com as Notas Fiscais...
Já os Itens de notas parece que está relacionando errado. Faça a seleção das NFs primeiro e depois você vê como faz com os itens.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que o erro está na igualdade de `Left Join`:

```
SELECT OrdensProducao.NumOrdem AS 'OP'
   ,OrdensProducao.NomeCliente AS 'Cliente'
   ,OrdensProducao.Descricao AS 'Descrição' 
   ,OrdensProducao.TipoProduto AS 'Produto'
   ,NomeAgencia AS 'Agência'
   ,OrdensProducao.DtEmissao
   ,SPreco AS 'Valor Fechado'
   ,SCustosComissoes AS 'Comissão'
   ,(SPreco - SCustosComissoes - SCustosMat - SCustosTerc - SCustosImpostos - SCustosFin - SCustosVenOutros) AS 'Contr Marginal'
   ,(SPreco - SCustosComissoes - SCustosMat - SCustosTerc - SCustosImpostos - SCustosFin - SCustosVenOutros - SCustosMO) AS 'Lucro'
   ,SUM(ItemNota.ValorTotal) AS 'Faturado'
FROM
    ((OrdensProducao INNER JOIN OrcHdr ON OrdensProducao.NumOrdem = OrcHdr.NumOrcamento)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ItemNota ON **OrdensProducao.NumOrdem** = ItemNota.NumOrdem)
     INNER JOIN NotasFiscais ON ItemNota.ObjID_Nota=NotasFiscais.ObjID

WHERE
    (NotasFiscais.NaturezaOperacao IS NULL OR (NOT NotasFiscais.NaturezaOperacao LIKE 'doa*' OR NotasFiscais.NaturezaOperacao LIKE 'reme*')) AND
    (ItemNota.Devolucao IS NULL OR ItemNota.Devolucao<> 'D') AND
    (NotasFiscais.Situacao IS NULL OR NotasFiscais.Situacao = 'N') AND
    (ItemNota.Fatura IS NULL OR ItemNota.Fatura = 'F')

GROUP BY
    OrdensProducao.NumOrdem
   ,OrdensProducao.NomeCliente
   ,OrdensProducao.Descricao 
   ,OrdensProducao.TipoProduto
   ,NomeAgencia
   ,OrdensProducao.DtEmissao
   ,SPreco
   ,SCustosComissoes
   ,(SPreco - SCustosComissoes - SCustosMat - SCustosTerc - SCustosImpostos - SCustosFin - SCustosVenOutros)
   ,(SPreco - SCustosComissoes - SCustosMat - SCustosTerc - SCustosImpostos - SCustosFin - SCustosVenOutros - SCustosMO)
ORDER BY
    OrdensProducao.NumOrdem
```